# How can I release captured text without adding a new line at the end?

Tags: shell, bioinformatics

I am trying to automate a Trimommatic analysis and to do it I tried to make a code that can read lines from a file called Samples_prefix.txt, and extract two variables:

**$sample** is the location of the file and **$sample_id** is the name of the sample.

Then I try to pass these variables with **${sample}** and **${sample_id}**

I tried the following code:

```
while read sample
do
sample_id=$(echo "$sample" | cut -d/ -f 4)
java -jar ./trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -threads 10 -phred33 **${sample}**_R1_001.fastq.gz **${sample}**_R2_001.fastq.gz **${sample_id}**_PE1.fq.gz **${sample_id}**_SE1.fq.gz **${sample_id}**_PE2.fq.gz **${sample_id}**_SE2.fq.gz HEADCROP:3 ILLUMINACLIP:./adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10 CROP:95 LEADING:10 TRAILING:10 SLIDINGWINDOW:5:20 MINLEN:50 2> **${sample_id}**.out
done < Samples_prefix.txt
```

The problem is when I try to use captured text **${sample}** or **${sample_id}**:

When the code runs, instead of getting for example: "text"+_R1_001.fastq.gz I get "text"end of the line, and then the _R1_001.fastq.gz.

Do someone know a way of fixing it?

My file looks like this:

../CleaningTranscriptoma/4_S637_L003-ds.7728b85c9e854b7bb5748534b1eba289/obic07c-f/obic07c-f

../CleaningTranscriptoma/6_S637_L003-ds.aa2df261cab44e1c9fe2ae4dbb7f0f09/obic08C-m/obic08C-m

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bash? Try quoting your variables and redirecting stdout/stderr and see if it helps, e.g.

```
while read -r sample
do
    sample_id=$(echo "${sample}" | cut -d/ -f 4)
    java -jar ./trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -threads 10 -phred33 "${sample}"_R1_001.fastq.gz "${sample}"_R2_001.fastq.gz "${sample_id}"_PE1.fq.gz "${sample_id}"_SE1.fq.gz "${sample_id}"_PE2.fq.gz "${sample_id}"_SE2.fq.gz HEADCROP:3 ILLUMINACLIP:./adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10 CROP:95 LEADING:10 TRAILING:10 SLIDINGWINDOW:5:20 MINLEN:50 1> "${sample_id}".out 2>"${sample_id}".err
done < Samples_prefix.txt
```

Also, for this type of domain-specific question https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ is typically more helpful, unless your question is specifically about programming.